# Orbifold CFT in the path integral formalism

Tags: conformal-field-theory, path-integral

The definition of an orbifold of a conformal field theory $X$ by a group action $G\times X\to  X$ is almost always phrased in the algebraic formalism of conformal field theories (Hilbert space, operator algebras, etc.). That is, if one knows the algebraic construction of a CFT $X$, then one can systematically construct the corresponding orbifold theory.

Does this also work in the path integral formalism? That is, given that one can write down a path integral for some CFT $X$, does there then exist a corresponding path integral describing the orbifold of $X$ by $G$?

As a concrete example, let $\Phi:\Sigma\to X$ be a set of fields living on some two-dimensional "worldsheet" $\Sigma$ and let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Sigma$ be a closed loop in the worldsheet. Then if there is a group action $G$ on $X$, we can construct an orbifold CFT by replacing the standard sigma-model path integral with

$$Z=\sum_{g\in G}\int_{\Phi(\gamma(1))=g\cdot\Phi(\gamma(0))}[\mathrm{d}\Phi]\exp\left(-S[\Phi]\right).$$

That is, we allow our path integral to include all twisted sectors of the group action. One concrete answer to my above question would essentially be to derive another set of fields $\Phi'$ (not necessarily sigma-model fields) such that this path integral is equal to

$$Z=\int_{\text{SBC}}[\mathrm{d}\Phi']\exp\left(-S'[\Phi']\right),$$

where, here, SBC stands for standard boundary conditions (i.e. non-twisted).

Comment: If your fields were valued in some space $V$, then I think it should be sufficient to take them valued in $V/G$. In particular, if your spatial slice is a circle, you should allow twisted sectors: when your fields are not periodic, but get changed by an element of $G$ after you go around the circle. I am not 100% sure though, so not making an answer.

Comment: I mean, this makes sense. If my fields $\Phi$ live in some space $V$, then generalizing the periodic boundary conditions for a CFT on (say) a cylinder to include all possible twisted boundary conditions will definitely suffice. But I wonder if there is a way to redefine the fields such that some new set of fields $\Phi'$ obeys standard periodic boundary conditions, but such that the two partition functions are the same..

Comment: Yes, although I personally don't know where the details have been worked out explicitly.  The procedure however (how to evaluate path integrals with matter CFT's with discrete symmetries) is outlined in Polchinski vol.1 sec. 8.5.